# Error Code 113 when doing the RequestRecipientToken request

Tags: docusignapi

Getting the following when doing a RequestRecipientToken

113One or both of Username and Password are invalid.

Using this header:

X-DocuSign-Authentication: [REDACTED][REDACTED][REDACTED]

... which works when doing the CreateAndSendEnvelope transaction.

Comment: I think you would need to actually post the trace of what you are doing.  Maybe comment out parts of the authentication headers.  I just tried doing through the walkthrough of embedded sending and it worked just fine.

Comment: Tried to but the trace includes the XML with a bunch of links and won't let me post that.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use legacy authentication and instead use our modern OAuth. 
You can read all about it here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant